# Make soundcard visible to new user

Tags: debian, audio, raspberry-pi, wav, armbian

If it's relevant, I'm trying this on the Debian-derived Armbian 3.4, running on an Orange Pi Zero (Raspberry Pi "clone") board. As you will see below, the board can playback sound either through a "line out" interface to earphones, or through a HDMI interface if such a monitor is attached.

I have created a new user (say `user2`) that seems not to be able to see the sound cards.

Running `aplay -l` under different users returns different results:

- as `root`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: audiocodec [audiocodec], device 0: SUNXI-CODEC sndcodec-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sndhdmi [sndhdmi], device 0: SUNXI-HDMIAUDIO sndhdmi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

- as my default user `user1` (created by the system at first login):

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: audiocodec [audiocodec], device 0: SUNXI-CODEC sndcodec-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sndhdmi [sndhdmi], device 0: SUNXI-HDMIAUDIO sndhdmi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

- as my problematic user `user2` (created by me):

```
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

Obviously, playing a WAV file through `aplay` works for `root` and `user1`, but not for `user2`.

Any ideas what I need to do to make the soundcards visible to `user2`?

Comment: Check out the groups both users belong to (`groups user1 user2`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As root or with sudo

```
usermod -aG audio user2
```

This added the user2 in group audio.

The user has to logout and login again for the changes to take effect.

Comment: It was helpful to see what groups the users belonged to, as Stephen Kitt pointed out. Added my `user2` to the group `audio` as you suggested. I did need to restart a program that `user2` was running that called `aplay` - in complex cases a `shutdown -r now` might be handy just to be sure.